# using ISA to expose an internal MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, instruction-set

We have an **internal server** running an MVC3 application, which has been made available on our **external server** by using an ISA server.

However; it is not applying the CSS, as the references to the external site are not mapped correctly.

The main difference between the 2, that I can see, is **internally** it runs as an application on the internal server (`http://InternalServer/MVCSite`)

The **External Server** is seen as running as an application within a subsite (`http://ExternalDomain/SubSite/MVCSite`), this is what the world gets.

looking at the source the URL generated I can see that is behaves like the **internal site**, returning: `@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")` as `/MVCSite/Content/Site.css`.

And I have been looking at this article to see if it sheds any light: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885186

I have thought that it might be that the redirection cannot handle differences in site structures? So, modifying the internal site to reflect the external layout will fix any uses. Internally `InternalServer/MVCSite` becomes `ExternalDomain/SubSite/MVCSite`

I will add more as I find things out.

Comment: The wording in this question makes some important things difficult to understand. For example, it seems you have two identical sites/apps, one is made available externally using ISA by opening ports/protocols to the 2nd? - is that what you meant to say? Is it correct they're both running off the same server? If so, that could be tricky with ISA rules. Can you post the ISA rules/filters applied for the allowed site? Also, have you tried running the Fiddler add-on to see what's going on - and not getting through?

Comment: I have updated the question, that I think will answer some of your questions. They dont run on the same server. I cannot post the filters I am afraid, which probably wont help much. If I can get some help in understanding what I need to ask the network guys to do that will help.

Comment: If ISA is blocking the css content then it would help to post those filters and rules. FYI, the question still reads as if both sites come from same server. Can you try Fiddler against both to see the difference?

Comment: Afraid not, the CSS is there, if I directly browse for the css and tweak the URL to include the subsite in the url, it serves the file. the problem is that externally the references in the pages are not accounting for the url difference.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not related to isa, and there is probably a proper way to do this configuring it. However if you cannot find the right solution, `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` may help you.

Instead of using: `@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")`, you can try `@Url.Content(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath + "Content/Site.css")`

If this doesn't work, you can override the value of AppDomainAppVirtualPath using reflection. Have a look here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_24475811.html#a24591595.

```
Dim vpathTypeName As String = "System.Web.VirtualPath, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Dim virtualPath As Object = ReflectionHelper.Instantiate(vpathTypeName, New Type() {GetType(String)}, New Object() {"/"})
ReflectionHelper.SetPrivateInstanceFieldValue("_appDomainAppVPath", runtime, virtualPath)
```

It basically updates an static field with whatever value you need. You can validate the host header with : `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` and set the value to `/` or `/SubSite/`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm waiting for time to investigate this problem I will add this to the queue. Annoyingly I have found that this isn't just affecting MVC projects, this is also affecting `WebResource` references that are included by `ASP.NET` controls.